# How can I successfully make an Android app with a push notification using Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

So I started by watching a YouTube tutorial and was able to make a basic Android app (testing it through by connecting my phone, as my VMWare apparently can't handle an Android Emulator). I then watched a different tutorial about creating a push notification. When I went to test it out, pressing my Notification button did nothing.

I then went to https://developer.android.com/ and made sure I had everything done, including adding both implementation "androidx.core:core:1.6.0" and implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0") - (I wasn't sure which one I needed). I synced it, and ran it again, and it still didn't do anything. Please see below for my code. Button 3/Main Activity 3 is supposed to be the push notification.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "3";
private String tag = "State";
Button button;
Button button2;
Button button3;

private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello World!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String message = "This is a push notification";

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    MainActivity3.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this,
                    0,intent,0);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this, CHANNEL_ID
            )
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_message)
                    .setContentTitle("New Notification")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(
                    MainActivity.this);

            int notificationId = 1;
            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
        }
    });

    Log.i(tag, "onCreate");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(tag, "onStart");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(tag, "onResume");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i(tag, "onPause");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.i(tag, "onStop");
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Log.i(tag, "onRestart");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(tag, "onDestroy");
}
```

}

MainActivity3 code:

```
public class MainActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);

    String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
    textView.setText(message);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the [article](https://medium.com/nybles/sending-push-notifications-by-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-249aa34f4f4c) can help you to send a first push.